# Javascript: replace multiple identical parts in a string with different strings

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I am working on a "fill in the blanks" card game, (very) similar to Cards Against Humanity. In some cases, I want to update a string of text with multiple blanks ("My ______ is ______.", for example), but I'm having trouble replacing these identical blank fields with different strings. Let's say I'd like to turn my string into "My **cat** is **white**". How could I possibly make this happen? I can replace every blank space in my strings with the same piece of text, but I can't seem to alternate between them. I guess I could cut my string into pieces every time a blank space ends, replacing all fragments with the text I want, and then joining the strings together... but is there a simpler way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try internally using placeholders in your input string.  That is, consider using the following representation:

```
My {1} is {2}.
```

When you want to display the original version you had to your users, simply replace the `{1}`, `{2}`, etc. placeholders with underscores.  Then, when you need to fill in a particular blank, target the placeholder directly.

```js
var input = "My {1} is {2}.";
var display = input.replace(/\{\d+\}/g, "______");
console.log(display);
var result = input.replace("{1}", "cat");
result = result.replace("{2}", "white");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This seemed to work best for my application, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is using this regexp `_{1,6}` without the global flag `g`.

The call of the function `String.prototype.replace(regexpWithNoG, string)` will replace only the first match.

```js
let str = "My ______ is ______.";
    words = ["cat", "white"];

words.forEach(w => str = str.replace(/_{1,6}/, w));
console.log(str);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a function to get that result.

```
function replace(str,values){
  var parts=str.split(/[_]+/g)
  var result = []
  result.push(parts[0])
  for (var i=1; i<parts.length; i++){
    result.push(values[i-1])
    result.push(parts[i])
  }
  return result.join("")
}
```

Example:

```
alert(replace("asdad ___ asdasd ___ aaa",[1,2]))
```

Returns:

```
 "asdad 1 asdasd 2 aaa"
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BqBKbM?editors=1010